# Jenkins Pipeline emailext: How to access build object in pre-send script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-email-ext

I'm using Jenkins ver. 2.150.1 and have some freestyle jobs and some pipeline jobs.
In both job types I am using the emailext plugin, with template and pre-send scripts.

It seems that the *build* variable, which is available in the freestyle projects, is *null* in the pipeline projects.

The pre-send script is the following (just an example, my script is more complex):

```
msg.setSubject(msg.getSubject() + " [" + build.getUrl() + "]")
```

There is no problem with the msg variable.
In the freestyle job, this script adds the build url to the mail subject.
In the pipeline job, the following is given in the job console:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getUrl() on null object
```

The invocation of emailext in the pipeline job is:

```
emailext body: '${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html.custom.pipeline.sandbox.template"}', 
         presendScript: '${SCRIPT, template="presend.sandbox.groovy"}', 
         subject: '$DEFAULT_SUBJECT', 
         to: 'user@domain.com'
```

I would rather find a general solution to this problem (i.e. **Access the *build* variable in a pipeline pre-send script**), but would also appreciate any workarounds to my current needs:
**Access *job name*, *job number*, and *workspace folder* in a pipeline pre-send script.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the answer -

Apparently for presend script in pipeline jobs, the `build` object does not exist, and instead the `run` object does. At the time I posted this question this was still undocumented!

Found the answer in this [thread](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46485?focusedCommentId=364055&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-364055)

Which got the author to update the description in the [wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin):

> - run - the build this message belongs to (may be used with FreeStyle    or Pipeline jobs)
> - build - the build this message belongs to (only use with FreeStyle    jobs)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `build` in a [script](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#writing-libraries) like this:

```
// findUrl.groovy

def call(script) {
   println script.currentBuild.rawBuild.url
   // or if you just need the build url
   println script.env.BUILD_URL
}
```

and would call the script like this from the pipeline:

```
stage('Get build URL') {
    steps {
        findUrl this
    }
}
```

The `currentBuild` gives you a [RunWrapper](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html) object and the `rawBuild` a [Run](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but as I wrote in my question, I need to access the `build` from within an **emailext pre-send script in a pipeline build**, not from the pipeline script itself. i.e. in `presend.sandbox.groovy` in the example above. So I don't think this can help me.

Comment: Okay, maybe I still don't understand your usecase here, but the following works for me in a pre send script

```logger.println("${BUILD_URL}")```